# User Session Management with Spring (Business and Transaction Management)

Tags: java, spring, struts2

In my application

The web front end is done using `Struts` and `Spring` for Business and  transaction Management.

Now, Am implementing logging in the Business Logic side (beans).

The log should happen such that, every method in the Service, should have the logged in User Details

One approach would be sending the User Object to every method in Service, when it is been called from Servlet

But this would really be dirty.

Does spring/ struts2-spring support any other way to do this.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Spring AOP](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html) to do your logging for you (Accompanied By a logging framework), Struts2 has nothing to do with Spring AOP. Spring AOP can work on its own regardless if its a Web Application or a Swing application with Minimal Setup.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Spring AOP](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/) to do the logging. This will make code cleaner and you need not rely on developer to do the logging at each place. 
For printing the user details use [MDC](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html) feature of SLF4J. It is like a ThreadLocal hashmap which you can access from any where. So your entry method can put the userdetails to MDC and it can be accessed in your log method.